# ERROR A LA HORA DE ESTRUCUTRAR LOS DATOS RECIBIDOS PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Ayer tenía un error que ya me lo resolvieron, me traía todos los datos duplicados, ahora tengo problema en armar la estructura correctamente, a la hora de imprimir los datos para mostrarlos en el html, se me repiten todas las cosas por cada uno, se que lo estoy haciendo mal en esa parte, pero no se me ocurre como ya intente de todas las maneras posibles.

Trate de hacer un array_unique de ese valor, pero de todas formas que probe no pude.

El codigo que recibo es:

```
$recursos= getRecursos($idmateria);


foreach($recursos as $row){
    $listarecursos= null;
    $nombre= null;
    $descripcion= null;
    $descarga= null;
    $modulo =null;

    $nombre.= $row['nombre'];
    $descripcion.= $row['descripcion'];
    $descarga.= $row['descarga'];
    $modulo.= $row['id_modulo'];

    $listarecursos.="
    <h3 style='color: #1d1c1a;'>". $modulo."</h3>
    <span class='dropdown'>
    <button type='button' class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Filtrar recursos por <span class='caret'></span></button>
    <div class='dropdown-menu'>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Videos</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Textos</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>PDFs</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Exámenes</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Encuestas</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Otros</a>
    </div>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>

        <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <thead style='background-color: #fdd306'>
            <tr>
                <th scope='col'>Accion</th>
                <th scope='col'>Descripcion</th>
                <th scope='col'>Descarga</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p><ion-icon name='document-text'></ion-icon>".$nombre."</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>".$descripcion."</td>
                                <td>
                                ".$descarga."
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>";


                    echo $listarecursos;  
    }
```

La funcion :

```
function getRecursos($idmateria){
    $base = new Database;
    $base = Database::conectar();

    $query= $base->prepare("SELECT * FROM recursos_materia WHERE id_materia= :id ORDER BY id_modulo");
    $query->execute(['id' => $idmateria]);
    $result= $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

Y me lo muestra así :

Y yo quiero que la cosa se me vea así :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es tan complicado como parece, solo debes saber en qué momento hay un módulo diferente para mostrar el encabezado correspondiente:

```
// Crea una variable para saber cuándo enviar encabezados
$modulo = 0;
// Crea también una variable para generar la salida
$listarecursos= '';

foreach($recursos as $row){
    // Lo primero es analizar si hay que enviar encabezados
    if($modulo != $row['id_modulo']) {
        // El módulo actual es diferente al mostrado la última vez
    if($modulo > 0) {
            // Hay que cerrar tabla solo si ya se mostró un módulo
            $listarecursos .= "</tbody></table>";
        }
        // Actualizar la variable para evitar repetición de encabezados
        $modulo = $row['id_modulo'];
        // Encabezado de módulo e inicio de tabla
    $listarecursos .= "
    <h3 style='color: #1d1c1a;'>$modulo</h3>
    <span class='dropdown'>
    <button type='button' class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Filtrar recursos por <span class='caret'></span></button>
    <div class='dropdown-menu'>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Videos</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Textos</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>PDFs</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Exámenes</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Encuestas</a>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-item'>Otros</a>
    </div>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>

        <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <thead style='background-color: #fdd306'>
            <tr>
                <th scope='col'>Accion</th>
                <th scope='col'>Descripcion</th>
                <th scope='col'>Descarga</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    ";
    }
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
    $descarga = $row['descarga'];

    // Solo se muestra tr de cada elemento
    $listarecursos.="
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p><ion-icon name='document-text'></ion-icon>$nombre</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>$descripcion</td>
                                <td>$descarga</td>
                            </tr>
   ";
}
// Si se mostraron módulos, una tabla quedó sin cerrar
if($modulo > 0) {
    $listarecursos .= "</tbody></table>";
}

// Muestra el HTML hasta haber terminado
echo $listarecursos;
```

Comment: Me anduvo perfectamente, sos un genio!! Mil gracias, claro yo intente de hacer más o menos la forma que lo planteaste pero en vez de $modulo != $row['id_modulo'] lo hacía con la misma variable del modulo, pero claro, así nunca iba a ser posible. Te debo una, mil gracias!

Comment: Igual si podrías explicarme algo, no entiendo como cerras las tablas de esta forma y por que repetis dentro del foreach y al final   if($modulo > 0) {
            // Hay que cerrar tabla solo si ya se mostró un módulo
            $listarecursos .= "</tbody></table>";
        }

Comment: Dentro del ciclo hay que cerrar solo si ya se mostró un módulo, porque en la primera vez todavía no se ha creado una tabla, la variable `$modulo` es cero.  Al salir de ciclo, si hubo resultados, el último registro deja una tabla abierta y se debe cerrar, la variable.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al aplicar el for each para cada elemento estas creando un nuevo menú por cada elemento, debes de llamar el for dentro de la tabla para iterar en el cada elemento y generar cada elemento por separado DENTRO de un único menú.

Comment: Graciasss!! Entendí lo que dijiste, se valora el aporte!